# Comparing nested data structures containing potentially empty arrays of primitives with clojure.data/diff

Tags: arrays, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I am using clojure.data/diff to compare nested data structures in my unit tests. It worked fine until I bumped into the issue that it (IMO) behaves inconsistently when encountering empty arrays of primitives.

Non-empty arrays of primitives compare fine against vectors containing same type of objects (e.g. doubles). However, empty primitive arrays do not compare equal (in diff function's sense) to an empty vector or even another empty array of the same type.

Here's a repl session showing my problem. I've added some comments.

```
nerom.nsd.dbserver=> (require '[clojure.data :as cd])
nil
;; this is as I would expect - a vector and a primitive array with 
;; same contents compare equal
nerom.nsd.dbserver=> (cd/diff [[1.1 2.2]] [(double-array [1.1 2.2])])
[nil nil [[1.1 2.2]]]
;; this is inconsistent with the previous - empty double array does 
;; not compare equal to an empty vector
nerom.nsd.dbserver=> (cd/diff [[]] [(double-array [])])
[[nil] [nil] nil]
;; two double arrays with the same contents compare equal
nerom.nsd.dbserver=> (cd/diff [(double-array [1.1 2.2])] [(double-array [1.1 2.2])])
[nil nil [[1.1 2.2]]]
;; except when they are empty, which is IMO inconsistent
nerom.nsd.dbserver=> (cd/diff [(double-array [])] [(double-array [])])
[[nil] [nil] nil]
```

What could I do to make empty arrays compare equal to an empty vector or at least an empty vector of the same type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I've found a clue:

if you take a look at the `diff` source you would see the following:

```
(if (= a b)
    [nil nil a]
    (if (= (equality-partition a) (equality-partition b))
      (diff-similar a b)
      (atom-diff a b)))
```

two values are first compared with an `equality-partition` , defined in a protocol `EqualityPartition`, which returns some keyword equality class

so if you extend this protocol to primitive arrays, they won't be considered equal:

```
(require '[clojure.data :as d])
```

before:

```
user> (d/diff [(double-array [])] [(int-array [])])
[[nil] [nil] nil]
```

and then you extend protocol:

```
(extend-protocol d/EqualityPartition
  (Class/forName "[D")
  (equality-partition [_] :double-array))

(extend-protocol d/EqualityPartition
  (Class/forName "[I")
  (equality-partition [_] :int-array))

user> (d/equality-partition (double-array []))
:double-array
user> (d/equality-partition (int-array []))
:int-array
```

after:

```
user> (d/diff [(double-array [])] [(int-array [])])
[[#object["[D" 0x1e2f0f97 "[D@1e2f0f97"]] [#object["[I" 0x207c60b5 "[I@207c60b5"]] nil]
```

while similar-type arrays will be compared as before

```
user> (d/diff [(double-array [])] [(double-array [])])
[[nil] [nil] nil]

user> (d/diff [(double-array [1])] [(double-array [10])])
[[[1.0]] [[10.0]] nil]
```

so looking further to this direction: you can tune the comparison extending this protocol (and other protocols from `clojure.data`)

Comment: Thanks! I think this enables me to do the comparisons as I want (e.g. comparing an empty double array to an empty vector). 
I already hacked my way out of the case I have at hand but I think I will need to make use of your idea soon.